# Multiply tensor with matrix while flattening

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I have a tensor A (could be any dimension) and a Matrix M. I would like to multiply them by flattening the tensor to have a matrix.

On MATLAB, I could simply do this:

```
function B = multiplyflatten(A,M)
B = M*A(:,:)
```

For the purposes of testing, one could run the above function with

```
A=rand(8,5,4,4)
B=rand(1,8)
```

How can one get something equivalent on python using numpy ndarrays?The below chunk wouldn't produce something equivalent

```
def multiplyflatten(A,M):
    B=np.matmul(M,A[:,:])
```

`A(:,:)` is compressing many dimensons into the second dimension of a matrix in MATLAB. Is there an easy way to do this on Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand *`A(:,:)` is compressing many dimensons into the second dimension of a matrix in MATLAB* correctly, the final `A(:,:)` has the shape of (8,5*4*4) as in example of `A=rand(8,5,4,4)`. In that case, this should be equivalent of `A(:,:)`:

```
A = A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1, order='F')
```

The -1 implicitly calculates the remaining shape required to fit `A` into a 2-D matrix. According to @hegdep's comment, matlab's default format of storing arrays is `F.contiguous` (vs. numpy's default storing in `C-contiguous` format).

Comment: `A = A.reshape(A.shape[0], -1,order="F")` produces the same results as with MATLAB.

Comment: According to your comment, matlab must have stored arrays in Fortan-contiguous rather than numpy default C-contiguous.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the case. Just wanted it to be out there, just in case somebody else was looking at similar translation.

Comment: Great. I will edit post accordingly. Thank you for the note.

Comment: The F-contiguous order of matlab is a fundamental aspect of the language. It's more common knowledge than an arcane detail. (+1 btw)

Comment: My knowledge of matlab is limited. Thank you for the upvote.